# How to convert JSON key-value pairs to records in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a series of JSONs that look something like this:

```
{
    id: '121',
    values: {
        "Value A": 1, 
        "Value B": 2, 
        "Value C": 3
    }
}
```

The number of key-value pairs can vary.

I want to create a pyspark program that would take this and break this down into a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
id  | key     | value
____ _________ ______
121 | Value A | 1
121 | Value B | 2
121 | Value C | 3
```

I was able to get the id and value columns using this:

```
df = sess.read.json('Projects/spark/data/*')
df.select('id',explode(array(expr('values.*'))).name('vals')).dropna().show()
```

But I haven't been able to find a method to extract the keys. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you please help accept the solution if it helped you ..

Answer (score 1):

I read the json which gives `MapType` as dtype for `values`. Then i simply extract keys using `map_keys` and values using `map_values` and then just explode the arrays.

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip, col, explode, map_keys, map_values

json1={
          'id': '121',
          'values': {
              "Value A": 1, 
              "Value B": 2, 
              "Value C": 3
          }
      }
df2=spark.createDataFrame([(json1)])





df2.select(col('id'),col('values'), map_keys("values").alias("keys"), 
           map_values("values").alias('inner_values'),
           ).withColumn("tmp",arrays_zip("keys","inner_values"))\
           .withColumn("tmp",explode("tmp")).select(col("id"),\
 col("tmp.keys"),col("tmp.inner_values")).show()

+---+-------+------------+
| id|   keys|inner_values|
+---+-------+------------+
|121|Value C|           3|
|121|Value A|           1|
|121|Value B|           2|
+---+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**A more simpler solution would be to use  **`explode()`** and **`select()`** together**

## Create the DF here

```
a_json={
          'id': '121',
          'values': {
              "Value A": 1, 
              "Value B": 2, 
              "Value C": 3
          }
      }
df = spark.createDataFrame([(a_json)])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

## Output

```
+---+------------------------------------------+
|id |values                                    |
+---+------------------------------------------+
|121|[Value C -> 3, Value A -> 1, Value B -> 2]|
+---+------------------------------------------+
```

## logic Here : Select() with explode() together

```
df = df.select("id", "values", F.explode("values").alias("x", "y"))
df.show(truncate=False)
+---+------------------------------------------+-------+---+
|id |values                                    |x      |y  |
+---+------------------------------------------+-------+---+
|121|[Value C -> 3, Value A -> 1, Value B -> 2]|Value C|3  |
|121|[Value C -> 3, Value A -> 1, Value B -> 2]|Value A|1  |
|121|[Value C -> 3, Value A -> 1, Value B -> 2]|Value B|2  |
+---+------------------------------------------+-------+---+
```